# JSON Show result on partial hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a piece of code which works with JSON to read values from a file, I got it working to display the results I need when I have a full match and a way that shows all the data all the time, both not what I need. I started the code out with a CSV file, but due the amount of data this was too slow, thus the switch to JSON (see: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237942/ajax-csv-undefined-array-values))

The code I have now with the JSON is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var airports; //Prepare variable for storing JSON data

    d3.json("airport.json", function(data) {
      airports = data; //put the JSON data into an easy to call variable
      continueCode(); //This is so we can use the JSON data outside of this call
    });

    function continueCode(){
      var result; //Prepare result variable for usersearches
      //User is typing in departure field
      $(".input-leave").on("keyup paste", function(){
        $("#display").empty();
        //Grab user input
    var userInput = $(".input-leave").val();
    if(userInput != ''){
      console.log("User input: "+userInput);
      //console.log(airports[0]["Country Code"]);
      for(var i=0; i<airports.length; i++){
        /* Prepare Variables for checking columns of JSON
           cnCode = Country Code
           ctCode = City Code
           stCode = State Code
           apCode = Airport Code
           apName = Airport Name
        */
        var cnCode = airports[i]["Country Code"],
            ctCode = airports[i]["City Code"],
            stCode = airports[i]["State Code"],
            apCode = airports[i]["Airport Code"],
            apName = airports[i]["Airport Name"];
        //Check if user input matches one of our variables

        //This shows the airports on an exact match
        if((userInput.toLowerCase() == cnCode.toLowerCase()) || (userInput.toLowerCase() == ctCode.toLowerCase()) || (userInput.toLowerCase() == stCode.toLowerCase()) || (userInput.toLowerCase() == apCode.toLowerCase()) || (userInput.toLowerCase() == apName.toLowerCase())){
          $("#display").append("Country Code: "+cnCode+", City Code: "+ctCode+", State Code: "+stCode+", Airport Code: "+apCode+", Airport Name: "+apName+"<hr>");
        }

        //This results in every airport being shown at all times
        if((userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(cnCode.toLowerCase())) !== -1 || (userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(ctCode.toLowerCase())) !== -1 || (userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(stCode.toLowerCase())) !== -1 || (userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(apCode.toLowerCase())) !== -1 || (userInput.toLowerCase().indexOf(apName.toLowerCase())) !== -1){
          $("#display").append("Country Code: "+cnCode+", City Code: "+ctCode+", State Code: "+stCode+", Airport Code: "+apCode+", Airport Name: "+apName+"<hr>");
        }
      }
    }else{
      $("#display").empty();
    }
  });
}
});
```

As you can see I have 2 ways of reading the data now, one that shows the data on a full string match and one that display all the data at any string.
What I need is for the data to be displayed on a partial string hit (example: user types 'Am', results display everything starting with 'am' in any column).

I have looked around here on SO and on Google, but everything I find is for displaying partial data, where the user sends an input and the result is for example an ID and name, I need to show the data while the user is inserting the data however so that won't work for me, is there a quick and easy way of solving this? I have been unable to find any JSON plugins that could do it for me, I have considered trying it with ElasticSearch, but I'm unsure as to how I should get started on that and if it will do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Autocomplete Widget | jquery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

The basic usage is to specify the source array.

Comment: I've tried it like this `$(".input-leave").autocomplete({
              source: airports
            });` but I keep getting a No results found, I'm using the Jquery-UI 1.12.1 and Jquery 1.12.4

Comment: As answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435433/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json) _You need to transform the object you are getting back into an array in the format that jQueryUI expects_

Comment: Based on your answer, and comment I've tried several things, one of them seems to never do anything and this code: `$(".input-leave").autocomplete({ minLength: 2, source: function(request, response){ var matcher = new RegExp("^"+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term),"ig"); response($.grep(airports, function(item){ return matcher.test(item); })); } });` always returns False. Do you maybe have an example I could have a look at to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Added `append("<li>"+airports[i]+"</li>");
                    appendTo(ul);` to the return matcher.test which I changed into `return matcher.test(item["City Code"]);` I have a list showing up but there is no content at all.. -- Edit: Forgot to mention, the search now shows the correct amount of results as `x results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.`